# Directive that create a select component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create a directive that create a select component in my page, but it doesn't work. Here is my code (directive):

```
module.directive(
  'myDirective',
  function($compile) {

  var construct = function(){
    var options = [1, 2, 3];
    return "<select ng-model='mychoice' ng-options='value for value in "+options+"'></select>
  };
    return {
      restrict : 'E',
      replace : true,
      scope : {
        data: '='
      },
      link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch('formElements', function (value) {
          if(typeof value !== "undefined"){
            element.html(construct());
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be including the element by yourself. Here it is a `plunker` with a directive that inserts a select element.

http://plnkr.co/edit/6rox9NWEhtet7f8unUHi?p=preview

In your html you can use it like this: `<select-directive options="options" ></select-directive>`

The definition is the following:

```
app.directive('selectDirective', selectDirective);

function selectDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        scope: {
            options: '='
        }
    }
}
```

And template.html just includes the select element:

```
<select ng-model='mychoice' ng-options='value for value in options'>
</select>
```

You can use this example and modify it for covering your own needs.

**EDIT**

Here is a new plunker in which the options array is being assigned depending on the data recieved by the directive. http://plnkr.co/edit/NjneCDd7VE0A30UaSZRM?p=preview

Comment: But I can't send my options array from html. I construct it in my directive.

Comment: why cant you contruct it in your controller as in the example?

Comment: I contruct it from my data (check my example)

Comment: Take a look at the edited answer, I believe is what you need!